# How this code works? Bitwise C language

Tags: c

I have to work with a code given by my school but I don't understant this function about shifts, bitewise

If someone could help me. It would be really nice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, character e in ASCII is hex `65` = binary `01100101`

What the code does is to shift right that value one more bit on every iteration, and when the rightmost bit after shift is 1 it fires SIGUSR1, else SIGUSR2.

Now, if you ask me what that code's useful effect might be, I have no clue.

Comment: (for ASCII) The bit pattern for 'e' should be `01101001` (no leading '1' bit)

Comment: @wildplasser thanks for the tip, corrected - actually the second nibble was wrong too, so it should be 01100101

Comment: Ah! I had overlooked that one. It would have been an 'i'.

Answer (score 5):

It is overly complex. Better shift the bit pattern by one click on each iteration:

```
int c ;
for (c = 'e'; c; c>>=1)
{
   kill(pid, (c & 1) ? SIGUSR1 : SIGUSR2);
}
```

As a side effect, this avoids the magic constant `8` (which should have been `CHAR_BIT`, IMHO)

BTW: this code is not *exactly* equivalent, the original always issues 8 kill() invocations, this one will stop after the seventh (given CHAR_BIT==8) , so an extra

```
kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
```

Would be needed to complete the job.

Answer (score 1):

It's a terrible way of writing `c & (1 << charac)`. It tests if the charac'th bit is set, then use SIGUSR1, otherwise SIGUSR2.

Answer (score 0):

`c >> charac`  shift the bits right charac times  ( so if charax is 3 it will bitshift  right 3 times

`& 1`  tests the lowest bit to set if its set

`?  SIGUSr1 : SIGUSR2`    this uses the result of the previous test, if its set, use sigusr1, otherwise use sigusr2